# Cross loop operation on pyspark dataframe

Tags: loops, pyspark

I have 2 columns(lat_lon) in pyspark dataframes( say DF1, DF2).

```python
DF1:
lat_lon
-84.412977,39.152501
-84.416946,39.153505

DF2:
lat_lon
-85.412977,39.152501
-85.416946,40.153505
```

I want to cross loop for each element of DF1 against each element of DF2 and calculating distance using a function. Now based on distance I am saving count as value corresponding to the row of DF1.

Example:

```python
list1=[[-84.412977,39.152501],[-84.416946,39.153505]]   
list2=[[-85.412977,39.152501],[-85.416946,40.153505]]   

list4=[]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    count=0
    for j in range(len(list2)):
        if (Haversine(list1[i],list2[j]).meters )<500:
               count+= 1
    list4.append(count)
```

How do I do this looping for columns of pyspark dataframe DF1 against DF2 and add count variable(as in list4) to DF1, as pyspark dataframe doesn't support indexing

Haversine function:

```python
import math

class Haversine:
    '''
    use the haversine class to calculate the distance between
    two lon/lat coordnate pairs.
    output distance available in kilometers, meters, miles, and feet.
    example usage: Haversine([lon1,lat1],[lon2,lat2]).feet

    '''
    def __init__(self,coord1,coord2):
        lat1,lon1=coord1
        lat2,lon2=coord2

        R=6371000                               # radius of Earth in meters
        phi_1=math.radians(lat1)
        phi_2=math.radians(lat2)

        delta_phi=math.radians(lat2-lat1)
        delta_lambda=math.radians(lon2-lon1)

        a=math.sin(delta_phi/2.0)**2+\
           math.cos(phi_1)*math.cos(phi_2)*\
           math.sin(delta_lambda/2.0)**2
        c=2*math.atan2(math.sqrt(a),math.sqrt(1-a))

        self.meters=R*c                         # output distance in meters
        self.km=self.meters/1000.0              # output distance in kilometers
        self.miles=self.meters*0.000621371      # output distance in miles
        self.feet=self.miles*5280               # output distance in feet

if __name__ == "__Haversine__":
    main()
```

Error that I am getting with suggested solution:

```python
var=df1.crossJoin(df2)\
    .withColumn("meters", haversine_udf(df1.lat, df1.lon, df2.lat, df2.lon))\
    .filter("meters < 500")\
    .groupBy(df1.lat, df1.lon)\
    .count()

var.schema
StructType(List(StructField(lat,DoubleType,true),StructField(lon,DoubleType,true),StructField(count,LongType,false)))


var.select('count').show(1)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o4346.showString.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid PythonUDF <lambda>(lat#126, lon#127, lat#131, lon#132), requires attributes from more than one child.
```

Comment: You sure you want to use Spark for this? Doesn't sound like a job suitable for Spark at all...

Comment: I want to parallelize the distance calculation. Is it possible to process calculation of each row(or bunch of rows) of DF1 against rows of DF2 in parallel and then aggregate the results

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

First let's create the dataframes

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(list1, ['lat', 'long'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(list2, ['lat', 'long'])
```

You'll have to create a `UDF` with your `Haversine` function:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

haversine_udf = psf.udf(lambda lat1, long1, lat2, long2: Haversine([lat1, long1], [lat2, long2]).meters, DoubleType())
```

Finally to get each element of `df1` against each element of df2, you can use a `crossJoin` (costly):

```py
df1.crossJoin(df2)\
    .withColumn("meters", haversine_udf(df1.lat, df1.long, df2.lat, df2.long))\
    .filter("meters < 500")\
    .groupBy(df1.lat, df1.long)\
    .count()
```

You can increase computation by `broadcast`ing one of your dataframes if it is small, this will copy it to every nodes memory:

```py
df1.crossJoin(psf.broadcast(df2))
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems promising. I assigned var=df1.crossjoin(df2)... How do I access count value for df1 rows? This is throwing me error: var.select('count').show(1)

Comment: I didn't have access to your `Haversine` function, so I couldn't test it. What error do you get?

Comment: added haversine function

Comment: I'm not getting any error. Could you update your question with the trace of the error?

Comment: Not error in running, but accessing the count variable. how do i do that?

Comment: You're using Spark 1.6?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158684/discussion-between-muni-and-maff).

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
id1=ds1.select('lat1','lon1').rdd.map(lambda l: (l[0],l[1]))
id2=ds2.select('lat2','lon2').rdd.map(lambda l: (l[0],l[1]))

mm=id1.cartesian(id2)
kk=mm.map(lambda l: Haversine(l[0],l[1]).meters)
```